# C++ / Qt - QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() does not show expected extension on MAC OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qfiledialog

I want to use a native file dialog to let the user choosing a .zip file

So I call following Qt static method with zip extension as expected file type

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Please select a zip file", "/home", "*.zip");
```

The behaviour is OK, the dialog is well expecting a ZIP file but the extension is not explicitly displayed anywhere on the dialog box. 
That can be disturbing for the user.

I try to find some others file dialogs in other apps under Mac OSX (Mavericks), I found one with an additional bottom panel showing the expected file type.

Anyone knows how can I also get the same kind of file dialog showing the expected file type?

Comment: I doubt that you can.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I guess you're right regarding information I can find about this, I finally specify the expected extension in the title of the filedialog.